# Curve looking weird, maybe missing vertex?

Tags: vertices, fcurves

I'm pretty new to blender, just learning. I followed tutorial for a chair and everything was going well up to this point, when one of my curves is really bad..

[image: Messed up curve]

I don't know what I messed up and don't know how to fix it, but it should looks like this:

[image: Correct curve]

when I add one vertex to the point where it obviously missing, it looks like this:

[image: Not fixed]

so it's not helping, it is possible to fix this ?!

Comment: It looks lie you are missing a face rather than a vertex.  The face to the left of your arrow appears not to be there.  I would try adding that face.  Otherwise, can you share your blend file?

Comment: I don't know how to add face, when I switch to faces (hotkey 3), it's impossible to click there to add faces.. as I said, I'm pretty new to blender, don't know much stuff, but here's blend file https://easyupload.io/qiixoi

Comment: switch to edge select mode (by typing 2 on the keyboard, NOT the number pad if you have one,) and select the edge going back from the vertex you have selected.  Then use shift and select the other top edge that runs parallel to it.  Type F to add the face.  Then type 1 on the keyboard to go back to vertex select mode

Comment: sorry, I don't have a clue which edges you are referring, I'm affraid, that I need to see visual.. I tried some combinations though, but none of them works.. btw: the top face should be missing, its intentional..

Comment: nevermind, I scraped that and started all over from scratch..